# Get GOS attachment list for notification via BAPI

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi, function-module

I need to find a BAPI (or a chain of BAPIs?) to read the Notification Attachment List (GOS) using as input the Notification number.

[image]

I've tried many BAPIs, but the only functional result was via `SO_OBJECT_READ` FM to which I passed Object ID (which I obtained from SOOD table).

[image]

Problem is that I'm unable to retrieve the attachment object list belonging to the notification.
Any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `BDS_GOS_CONNECTIONS_GET` function module to retrieve attachment list for notification. Specify parameters like this:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BDS_GOS_CONNECTIONS_GET'
  IMPORTING
   logical_system  = <system name> * << optional parameter       
   classname       = BPR_NOTIF     * << object type for notifications     
   objkey          = 1014866112016 * << your notification number + year        
   client          = XXX
  TABLES
   gos_connections = lt_attachments
.
```

The attachments links can be found in `SRGBTBREL` table and FM `OBJKEY` parameter corresponds to `INSTID_A` field of this table.

Comment: Hello, using as classname "BUS2080" and as objkey notification only it works. The problem is that I cannot use a Functional Module, I need to use a BAPI.

Comment: BAPI is nothing more than special-case function module. Tell me the reason for strong BAPI requirement.

Comment: Because in my use case I need to use standard RFC BAPI, FM are not exposed to RFC.

Comment: But if you have access to backend, you can create z-copy of the above FM and make it remote-enabled.

Comment: That's correct: I should avoid a z-copy, just wondering if there was a standard already exposed BAPI, but it seems not. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, by tcode QM03 I have a notification number and I wanted to know the table where stored the data of all atachments.

Go to transaction OAOR (Business Document Navigator), enter:
Class name: QMSM
Class Type: BO
Execute and complete two fields: Notification number and task number. Below the folder General documents you will get the attachment files by date created.

Other way, execute BDS_GOS_CONNECTIONS_GET with the same parameters in:
CLASSNAME: QMSM
OBJKEY: &notification_number& + &task number&.